# Tesseract 4 couldn't load any languages when used with OCR Engine mode - "Legacy + LSTM engines" (--oem 2)

Tags: ocr, lstm, tesseract

I think this issue is only related to Tesseract 4 which comes with LSTM support. As I am using a 64-bit Windows System, I have downloaded [64-bit windows executable](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v4.1.0.20190314.exe) from here - https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

It has the following OCR Engine modes:

- 0    Legacy engine only.
- 1    Neural nets LSTM engine only.
- 2    Legacy + LSTM engines.
- 3    Default, based on what is available.

It works with all the modes except **2**.

---

### When run with --oem 1

```
tesseract --oem 1 1.jpg 1
```

Result:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0.20190314 with Leptonica
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 561
Detected 5 diacritics
```

and creates a file **1.txt** with corresponding OCR result.

---

### When run with --oem 2

```
tesseract --oem 2 1.jpg 1
```

Result:

```
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
```

and no output is generated.

---

I thought the error will be with language installation but

```
tesseract --list-langs
```

which gave me the following result

```
List of available languages (2):
eng
osd
```

I even manually checked the **tessdata** folder, here is the screenshot of the same

[image]

which clearly states I already have **eng** language.

> Can anyone help me with the exact problem that is disallowing me use
>   Legacy + LSTM engines (--oem 2) mode.

Comment: Date of your eng.traineddata seems to differ from other tesseract - related stuff. How did you get eng.traineddata? Are you sure it matches tesseract version?

Comment: From the same source, I mentioned in the question - " I have downloaded [64-bit windows executable](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v4.1.0.20190314.exe) from here - https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki ". It came with the package itself. No extra download was required.

Also, can you mention how to check the compatibility of the eng.traineddata?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you have **eng** language, but with LSTM support only. If you want to have LSTM&Legacy support you need to download data from [tessdata repository](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata)